# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object on line 24

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Good day,

I'm running a blog page, that's `PHP`. I was using `PDO` for the connection string, and things worked perfectly.

I have now, recently uploaded to my server, and now I had to change to using `mysqli`.

I am new to using this format, as I have always used `PDO`.

My coding is below, could someone please assist?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['cmdPost']))
 {
        try
        {
        $name = $_POST['txtname'];
        $subj = $_POST['txtsubject'];
        $msg = $_POST['txtmessage'];

            if(empty($name) || empty($subj) || empty($msg))
                throw new Exception("Error - Please fill in input fields!");

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs VALUES (name, subject, message)");
        $stmt->bind_param($name, $subj, $msg);
```

This is where I'm getting the error:

```
"Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/m4230930/public_html/blog.php on line 24"
```

I have been stuck on this for 3 solid days, I am unsure how to continue.

Could someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: `$dbh->prepare()` is getting an error and returning false instead of a statement.

Answer (score 3):

change following line :

```
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs VALUES (name, subject, message)");
    $stmt->bind_param($name, $subj, $msg);
```

with :

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs (name, subject, message) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss',$name, $subj, $msg);
```

Comment: thanks :) that seems to have done the trick